# No longer able to copy file link in Dropbox after upgrading Mac to Yosemite

Tags: dropbox

I upgraded my Mac to OS to 10.10 Yosemite.  Dropbox no longer lets me copy the file link to send someone to let them download files. I don't get the choice anymore in my right click info. Can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or is Dropbox not able to do that anymore?

Comment: What version of Dropbox are you running?  They've released a number of updates recently (they normally install automatically, but if yours has not for some reason, try downloading the latest stable build listed on   https://forums.dropbox.com/ )

Comment: Because this has nothing to do with the Web interface, your question would be better off at [su], or perhaps [apple.se].

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using a 2.10.4x build of Dropbox. The current latest stable version is 2.10.45 and can be found at

https://forums.dropbox.com

Dropbox's Finder integration in Yosemite is very different because there is now an official way to have Dropbox integrate with Finder, rather than Dropbox having to inject its code into Finder.

(See the “Finder Sync Extensions” section of [OS X 10.10 Yosemite: The John Siracusa Review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/10/os-x-10-10/17/) for more details.)